# How to fix [BXSQ0001] An SQL exception occurred: 'No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://...?

Tags: jdbc, classpath, basex

I'm evaluating use of Base-X's SQL module with MySQL.

For a simple experiment I started with something similar to the example from http://docs.basex.org/wiki/SQL_Module:

> ```
> let $conn := sql:connect("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/coffeehouse")
> return sql:execute($conn, "SELECT * FROM coffees WHERE price < 10")
> ```

(I changed the URL to my mysql database's URL). First attempt results in the error

```
[BXSQ0001] An SQL exception occurred: 'No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname
```

I tried the obvious fix - dropped a copy of `mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar` into `C:\Program Files (x86)\BaseX\lib` and restarted. But the error remains.

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, putting the jdbc driver into the lib folder of BaseX should be enough. This works as expected at my system, using the MariaDB jdbc driver. Please check in Windows, that the jar files is actually included. By the way, BaseX is not an Apache project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BaseX ships with a couple of different start-up options - there is `basex.exe` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\BaseX` and `basex.bat` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\BaseX\bin`. The latter one seems to work as expected, the executable doesn't.